# Addtional parameter with @ngrx/entity

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity

I want to keep employee array and page loading status in store state. So my initial state will look like this

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  employees: []
  };
```

Now i want to use @ngrx/entity for employee instead of array. The documentation only show the demo for using entity with entire state.

How can i use entity for only one property rather than entire state?

If it's not possible what is the alternative for above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/interfaces) for an example:

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';

export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface State extends EntityState<User> {
  // additional entities state properties
  selectedUserId: number;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<User> = createEntityAdapter<User>();
```